# Facing problem within salt in CryptoJs with Laravel and Angular 6

Tags: angular, laravel, cryptojs

In Laravel5, I have encrypted message through the following salt and passed the salt value in API with base64 encoded:

```
    $data = [];
    $cipher = env('APP_CIPHER'); // AES-256-CBC
    $iv = random_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher));
    $key = env('APP_KEY'); // XXXXXZNUK5nhIMBbBEwKISqQ9ioXXXXX
    $value = \openssl_encrypt(
        json_encode($response),
        $cipher, $key, 0, $iv
    );
    $data['data'] = $value;
    $data['salt'] = base64_encode($iv);

    return $data;
```

In Angular 6, I want to decrypt the message. I did the following code but its showing me `malformed utf-8 data`:

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('XXXXXZNUK5nhIMBbBEwKISqQ9ioXXXXX');
var salt = atob(this.countryList.response.salt);
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(salt);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(this.countryList.response.data, key, {
keySize: 128 / 8,
iv: iv,
mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
console.log('utf8 = ' + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

The message/ values are stored into `this.countryList.response.data`

The base64 encoded salt value I received in `this.countryList.response.salt`.

Any mistake in my code?

Please note, If I do `$iv = '1212121212121212';` in Laravel and do `var salt = '1212121212121212';` in Angular, it returns the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

I made a mistake as above. I did the following :

```
var salt = (this.countryList.response.salt);
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(salt);
```

Note, I removed the atob function too.

So instead of `Utf8`, it should be `Base64`. So, the Angular code will be:

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('XXXXXZNUK5nhIMBbBEwKISqQ9ioXXXXX');
var salt = (this.countryList.response.salt);
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(salt);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(this.countryList.response.data, key, {
keySize: 128 / 8,
iv: iv,
mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
console.log('utf8 = ' + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```